# WatiN not responding to API calls

Tags: c#, .net, watin

some I'm back with a very perplexing problem.  I have written some classes using WatiN and the Interop libraries in .NET in order to open a separate Excel application, read a few URLs from some of the cells, and then use this list to have my IE browser navigate to these relevant websites and then capture screen shots.  However, after opening an Excel application using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel library APIs, my IE instance that was previously instantiated no longer will navigate to web pages or take focus on the screen in order to properly capture the full web pages.  It is still working however because it will capture really short but wide blank white images.  Has anyone else encountered similar problems with WatiN and other applications being run at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

While this may not be the answer for your question, there is one suggestion that I have. Have you considered reading Excel file without opening an instance of Excel using the Interop API?

Comment: // Open the Excel file for parsing
                _app = new Excel.Application();

                // Get a handle to the current workbook
                _wb = _app.Workbooks.Open(filePath);

                // Get a handle to the current worksheet
                _ws = (Worksheet) _wb.ActiveSheet;

This is how I am opening the Excel doc, but whenever the process that uses WatiN is complete, I seem to not be closing the hidden Excel process by looking at the Task Manager.  Should the GC of .NET not do this for me?